# conversion of byte array to string causing OOM

Tags: java, memory, byte

In my application i m storing strings using randomaccessfile and while reading back the string i need to convert byte array to string, which is causing OOM. Is there a better way to convert other than this

str = new String(b, "UTF-8");

where b is byte array

Comment: how big is that byte array? are you trying to read the whole file and convert it into a single string?

Comment: String constructor has little to no overhead. Any other method to build a string will end up with the same string using the same memory. Perhaps, you need to rethink your approach. Make sure that you're not misdiagnosing your issue.

Comment: Does the byte array contain a terminating 0?

Comment: Byte array would have strings like any country name, product name etc . I m not reading the entire file into byte array, but reading strings one by one as byte array and converting it to string before returning

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to convert other than `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` ?

This is actually a rather complicated question.

This constructor cannot simply incorporate the `byte[]` into the string:

- Prior to Java 9, it is always necessary to decode the byte array to a UTF-16 coded array of `char`.  So the constructor is liable to allocate roughly double the memory used by the source `byte[]`.
- With Java 9 you have the option of using a new compact representation for  `String`.  If you do the AND if the UTF-8 encoded byte array only contains code-points in Unicode code-plane zero (`\u0000` to `\u00ff`) then the `String` value is a `byte[]`.  However, even in this case the constructor must copy the bytes to a new `byte[]`.

In both cases, there is no more space-efficient way to create a `String` from a `byte[]`.  Furthermore, I don't think there is a more space-efficient way do the conversion starting with a stream of bytes and a character count.  (I am excluding things like modifying the `lava.lang.*` implementation, or breaking abstraction using reflection.)

Bottom line: when converting a `byte[]` to a `String` you should allow at least twice as much contiguous free memory as the original `byte[]` if you want your code to work on older JVMs.

Comment: I can only use java 6 for this . Any way i can clear off the string objects from heap which is created with new keyword.

Comment: No.  Let the GC deal with it.

Comment: I  m thinking if i serialize and deserialize those objects, will it help .

Comment: Nope.  I think you are probably looking for the wrong cause for the OOMEs.  Have you checked for memory leaks?  Using a memory profiler?  Have you checked that the byte arrays you are turning into strings have the correct length?  (A zero in the byte array does not terminate the string ...)